# run runas in a shell

Tags: passwords, windows, metasploit, script

I'm playing with a Windows 7 VM that I own.
I started a reverse shell with ncat as listener.
I can run commands except `runas`.
Whenever I try to switch to another user I got prompted for the password but the prompt is skipped instantly like I have pushed enter.

```
runas /user:test "cmd"
```

Is there a workaround to launch runas in a shell?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo password|runas /user:test "cmd"
```

Comment: It didn't works. I found an alternative using PsExec. http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-to-localhost-logon-failure_topic5398.html